# Generic awaited method to read and write to Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, async-await, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to create two methods to write and read to the Isolated Storage using PCLStorage, but i'm having some problems with the read (Get) part:

```
        public async static Task<T> GetObject()
        {
            IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("cache", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(T.GetType().Name);

            return await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
        }

        public async static void SetObject<T>(T obj)
        {
            IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("cache", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            await folder.CreateFileAsync(obj.GetType().Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to create two generic functions for my objects, the ones I want to store in isolated storage. My problem is that im stuck on how to "genericfy" GetObject as it returns `Task<TYPE>`, for instance `Task<string>`. Normally `T` is defined with the method name but here it needs to be defined with the task.

Comment: BTW, the names of asynchronous methods should end with `-Async`, e.g. `GetObjectAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still works the same, you have to define T after the method name:

```
public async static Task<T> GetObject<T>()
```

If you have that, you can then call it like this:

```
SomeType obj = await GetObject<SomeType>();
```

Although that wouldn't work directly with your current code, you have to somehow convert what `ReadAllTextAsyc` returns (presumably `string`) to `T`.